# Insert text in between file lines in python

Tags: python, io, insert, tokenize, writetofile

I have a file that I am currently reading from using

```
fo = open("file.txt", "r")
```

Then by doing

```
file = open("newfile.txt", "w")
file.write(fo.read())
file.write("Hello at the end of the file")
fo.close()
file.close()
```

I basically copy the file to a new one, but also add some text at the end of the newly created file. How would I be able to insert that line say, in between two lines separated by an empty line? I.e:

```
line 1 is right here
                        <---- I want to insert here
line 3 is right here
```

Can I tokenize different sentences by a delimiter like `\n` for new line?

Answer (score 6):

First you should load the file using the `open()` method and then apply the `.readlines()` method, which splits on `"\n"` and returns a list, then you update the list of strings by inserting a new string in between the list, then simply write the contents of the list to the new file using the `new_file.write("\n".join(updated_list))`

**NOTE:** This method will only work for files which can be loaded in the memory.

```
with open("filename.txt", "r") as prev_file, open("new_filename.txt", "w") as new_file:
    prev_contents = prev_file.readlines()
    #Now prev_contents is a list of strings and you may add the new line to this list at any position
    prev_contents.insert(4, "\n This is a new line \n ")
    new_file.write("\n".join(prev_contents))
```

Comment: If the file can loads fully into memory.

Comment: @Will, definitely for very large files, the OP has to `yield` the contents and write to a new file accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

`readlines()` is not recommended because it reads the whole file into memory. It is also not needed because you can iterate over the file directly.

The following code will insert `Hello at line 2` at line 2

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    with open('file2.txt','w') as f_out:
        for line_no, line in enumerate(f_in, 1):
            if line_no == 2:
                f_out.write('Hello at line 2\n')
            f_out.write(line)
```

Note the use of the `with open('filename','w') as filevar` idiom. This removes the need for an explicit `close()` because it closes the file automatically at the end of the block, and better, it does this  *even if there is an exception*.

Answer (score 0):

For Large file

```
with open ("s.txt","r") as inp,open ("s1.txt","w") as ou:
    for a,d in enumerate(inp.readlines()):
        if a==2:
            ou.write("hi there\n")
        ou.write(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

U could use a marker

```
#FILE1
line 1 is right here
<INSERT_HERE>                  
line 3 is right here
```

```
#FILE2
some text
```

```py
with open("FILE1") as file: 
    original = file.read()
with open("FILE2") as input:
    myinsert = input.read()

newfile = orginal.replace("<INSERT_HERE>", myinsert)

with open("FILE1", "w") as replaced:
    replaced.write(newfile)
```

```
#FILE1
line 1 is right here
some text                
line 3 is right here
```